# In Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade, was the Holy Grail lost for good?

Tags: indiana-jones, the-last-crusade

At the end of The Last Crusade, the Austrian woman attempted to take the Holy Grail beyond the great seal at the entrance of the temple.

In doing so, she caused the temple to quake and the Grail fell into a chasm that was created.

One of the last scenes in the temple shows the last Templar Knight waving bye to Indiana as the escaped.

Was the grail completely lost to the world now? Or did the Knight collect it and reset the temple for the next person to face the tests and discover the grail?

Comment: God moves in mysterious ways. Once you've accepted that this the *Holy Grail* you can't really say, can you?

Comment: The Holy Grail would not be lost for good, since it could easily be retrieved by an unladen swallow.

Comment: @Tango - African or European?

Comment: @DVK: If they're looking for the grail, and the grail isn't in Europe, they'd have to be African, of course!

Comment: there is something in the scene that reminds me of the LOTR ROTK scene - Gollum falling in the lava with the precious. Did Lucas steal from Tolkien ???

Comment: It was lost for ill really. Think of the lives that could have been saved with that thing. It wasn't good at all that it was lost ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Yes**

These people at [this reference](http://nitcentral.philfarrand.com/discus/messages/8/12105.html?1306683033), interpret the final grail scene the same way I do:

The Grail is **lost forever**. (bold mine)

> Elsa grabs it and runs off, but when she crosses a forbidden area, the
>   temple collapses, and Elsa and the Grail are **lost forever**.

The Wikia site for Indiania Jones says this about the [Holy Grail](http://indianajones.wikia.com/wiki/Holy_Grail)(bold mine):

> Indiana nearly tumbled into the abyss himself, but was caught by his
>   father. Indiana, like Elsa, tried to reach the cup, but was persuaded
>   by Henry to let it go.
>
> As a result, **the Grail was ultimately lost** following the events of the
>   adventure, but the experience gave both Indiana and his father the
>   chance to rekindle their rocky relationship.

Also that page mentions:

> Years later, the elder Jones remarked on the elusive, indefinite
>   nature of the Grail, commenting that the cup discovered by the
>   father-son team was simply "a Grail. But many of the oldest Grail
>   texts, written by the most ancient seers, refer to the Grail as an
>   elixir, as a bread, a powder, gold, or a stone."

Comment: "As a result, the Grail was ultimately lost following the events of the adventure, but the experience gave both Indiana and his father the chance to rekindle their rocky relationship"  - So two people may be friendlier for a few decades before dying.  Not much of a consolation to the rest of the world for millennia to com for the loss of the Holy Grail.

Comment: I wonder is it possible to just dig in that place and try to recover The Grail?

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi Of course, once you have the technology and the funding to dig that deep and sift through that amount of material (and know that it's there in the first place).

Comment: @TylerH I think the technology is already available, and people with money are ready to start the digging, simple like that.

Comment: Just image all those big holes in the earth where iron ore is mined. And in this case we  have the same hole, but with more deliberate devices, and infinite life is the prize. I bet USA will invade the whole region in the next hours )

Comment: You appear to have linked to speculation on a fansite. This is just people (with no connection to the makers of the film) guessing

Answer (score 3):

This part of the story was intended to be left as a mystery by the writer, and so the public would have to imagine (individually) what happened to the Grail.

Answer (score 2):

Another point in favor of 'yes': The Grail is seen (and noted in [the script](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/Indiana%20Jones%20And%20The%20Last%20Crusade.txt)) to be a **clay** cup with gold foil lining the bowl.

When it fell into the chasm, it undoubtedly shattered into a whole lot of shards and dust, so it isn't even a cup anymore.

Comment: But explicitly a *magic* cup, so really all bets are off...